# Capture or log the SQL queries, which Oracle database receive

Tags: oracle, relational-database, rdbms

I want to export information from a windows application, which manage the data in an Oracle database.
The problem is, I don't really know the data model e.g. all the tables and relationships, which save the information I need.
I thought, over the application GUI I could create some dummy data, display some data etc. and listen what the database receive(tables, columns etc.).
Is there an Oracle tool or any other appropriate tool, which I could use to capture the database queries, which the database receive?

Comment: How about tracing sessions?

Comment: I didn't know "SQL Trace" and took a look, it sounds good.